# Reinstall pods, clean project & derived data after each branch switch optimisation

Tags: ios, xcode, git, workflow, branch

I'm having this issue over and over. Every time I switch branches with different pods repos, my XCode apparently caches them and it fails to compile. So I have to **clean my project folder** and **clean the derived data** and **reinstall the pods**, and then everything works fine. But I have to do this every time I switch branches. Any idea how optimize the workflow here? Is there any script that I could use in the terminal after the branch switch that does this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `post-checkout` git hook to do some additional work after branch change. From [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout)

> **post-checkout**
>
> This hook is invoked when a git checkout is run after having updated
>   the worktree. The hook is given three parameters: the ref of the
>   previous HEAD, the ref of the new HEAD (which may or may not have
>   changed), and a flag indicating whether the checkout was a branch
>   checkout (changing branches, flag=1) or a file checkout (retrieving a
>   file from the index, flag=0). This hook cannot affect the outcome of
>   git checkout.

To do this, from the root folder of your project, do the following

```
cd .git/hooks
mv post-update.sample post-update
```

Now edit `post-update` file to add your cleanup and pod install commands.